SMD SOT-23-3 Part identification - top marking 3D sideways 9
I have a Lenovo Legion 7-17imh05h laptop that had a short on LVDS cable and I found that the part attached in the image is cracked and has various marks indicating that it has been burned. The part is near a QH1 marking and the top marking is .3D9 (the nine is sideways) or 3D9 (not sure if the dot is in the marking or if it's an artifact from heat). Would be grateful if I could identify this thing as I can't seem to find a board view for this laptop.


It is a LRB715FT1G/T3G common cathode dual diode from LRC (Leshan Radio Company). Marking "3D", "9" is a traceability code.
SOT323 package to be confirmed with a calliper (visually seems smaller than SOT23).
Picture from Taobao

